# Is it possible to use/define nested structure in CycloneDDS IDL file?

Tags: c++, idl, data-distribution-service

I found [RTI DDS](https://community.rti.com/kb/how-do-i-specify-nested-structure-key-my-data-type) and [OpenDDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278422/passing-complex-structure-from-opendds-publisher) are capable to define nested structures and complex structure in IDL file,

but couldn't find any example for [CycloneDDS](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds) on defining nested structures/ complex structures in the IDL file, does Cyclone DDS support nested structures in IDL? in the [cyclones developer guide](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/assets/pdf/CycloneDDS-0.1.0.pdf) they do not mention anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does. It is a standard OMG IDL feature and is the same across all DDS implementations.